# SObject row does not allow errors: error updating record

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

i'm getting an error from updating or saving a record on the following trigger:

```
trigger ActiveSave on CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c (before insert, before update) {

    for(CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c credRules : [SELECT Active__c FROM CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c 
                                              WHERE CreditInfo_Fields__r.Used__c = false 
                                              AND Id IN :Trigger.new]){
        if(credRules.Active__c == true){
            credRules.addError('The CreditInfo Field is not beeing used!');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can you use the addError method for only those records that are
>   available in Trigger Context.

```
trigger ActiveSave on CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c (before insert, before update) {

    for(CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c credRules : [SELECT Active__c FROM CreditInfo_Eval_Rules__c 
                                              WHERE CreditInfo_Fields__r.Used__c = false 
                                              AND Id IN :Trigger.new]){
        if(credRules.Active__c == true){
            trigger.newmap.get(credRules.id).addError('The CreditInfo Field is not beeing used!');
        }
    }
}
```

You need to change just one line i.e instead of **credRules.addError** use 
 **trigger.newmap.get(credRules.id).addError**.

> Triggers can be used to prevent DML operations from occurring by
>   calling the addError() method on a record or field. When used on
>   Trigger.new records in insert and update triggers, and on Trigger.old
>   records in delete triggers, the custom error message is displayed in
>   the application interface and logged.

reference:-

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm